# newtonsoft.json сохраняет в одну строчку

Tags: c#, json

Чтобы записать в json-файл данные использую newtonsoft.json. Он сохраняет всё в одну строчку, без уровней. Перепробовал несколько вариантов, но итог один... Как это можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
Product product = new Product
            {
                sss = new string[] { "sss:" + doc[0], "aaa: sdasdsa" },
                Slovo = "sss",
                Expiry = new DateTime(2005, 12, 12),
            };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JSON files(*.json)|*.json|All files(*.*)|*.*";
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return;
            string filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, json);
            MessageBox.Show("Файл сохранен");
```

Comment: Строка `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);`, после `product` поставьте формат (что то вроде: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, Formatting.Indented);`).

Comment: Благодарю.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, Formatting.Indented);